# Non expiring cache

Tags: php, caching

I'm developing a e-commerce system in PHP. I always want to display updated data to the customer, but a memory cache is necessary. 
I'm figuring if there is common to have non expiring cache, and delete the cache when the data is updated. Or is that bad practice?

Comment: Seems reasonable to me. The dangerous part is in potentially delivering old data. You have to be absolutely positive that your cache gets updated when the underlying data gets updated, regardless of the source of the update (if you have multiple apps on the database, or if someone manually edits the data directly).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm figuring to have a key/value database between DB and application (like redis or cassandra) instead of cache. That would probably be as fast as memcache, but only one item to keep track of when updating. What do you think of that idea?

Comment: Not sure - haven't tried that. Generally I just work with a regular database, and only cache things that don't have to be up-to-the-second live, and even then, with a short cache lifecycle (a few minutes tops). Database access in general is very fast by design, so unless you need to squeeze every microsecond out of your data access, you might be introducing more complexity than is necessary. It might be worth just using the database directly now, and see if that's good enough, and worry about a caching layer later only if it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a fairly high trafficked auction website and we had to do a lot of caching to keep the site up.

There were two kinds of cache invalidation that we used:

**Active**

For anything that changed very quickly we would use an active invalidation. For us it was bids/how much an item cost at any given moment. We would cache this information indefinitely and when someone bid on something, we would pro-actively purge the cache.

We kept the active purging to an absolute minimum though.

Also you want to make sure if you're pro-actively purging a cached object ... make sure it only exists in one place. It's too painful to try and search the cache for all instances and change them everywhere.

**Passive**

This is where you give an object a time to live (TTL) and let it gracefully expire on its own.  Use this for things that can afford to be a little stale.

We took this approach for 95% of our data and it worked great.

It's also very easy to program unlike the active invalidation.

---

For both active and passive cache invalidation ... I wouldn't say either is bad practice.